# PHP display JSON and XML

Tags: php

I am making use of an available API to send requests and receive the results which is in json and xml formats. I am able to do so but how do I display the returned data properly?

I used json_decode and assign the xml data to an array and print_r those. It shows up in a huge junk of data.

How do I show it on a table form? Or must I save the data into individual files or database first before displaying?

I am new to PHP, thus not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Would you be able to post the relevant sections of code?

Comment: Well you have to parse the xml with `DOMDocument` or similar and for json `json_decode` is enough.

Comment: If you want to see the `print_r()` in a nicer format you can view the HTML source in the browser, as the browser will render ignoring whitespace formatting so it will all show up in a giant blob of text. Or you can do this `echo '<pre>' . print_r($your_decoded_json) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a multidimensional-array, the easiest way to view it, in my opinion, is to just

```
var_dump($json_array);
```

Though, this may be the chunk of data you're referring to.

It's not a very table friendly format, as a table is inherently 2-dimensional, and JSON can be many-dimensional.

You can flatten the array, and then display it as a table.

```
function flatten_json($json, &$flat, $key) {

    // First check the base case: if the arg is not an array,
    //   then it's data to be inserted in the flat array.
    if (!is_array($json)) {
        $flat[$key] = $json;
    } else {

        // It's an array, to reduce the depth of the json,
        // we remove this array, by iterating through it,
        // sending the elements to be checked if they're also arrays,
        // or if they're data to be inserted into the flat array.

        foreach ($json as $name => $element) {
            flatten_json($element, $flat, $key.'_'.$name);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this function, you first declare you flat array:

```
$flat = array();
```

Then pass it to the function, with your json, and a key you want to be the outer key, if you are sure that your json is an array, which is pretty much guaranteed, you can leave the key empty.

```
flatten_json($json_array, $flat, '');
```

Now $flat will have the flattened json, and you can print it as a table, maybe into a csv if you have many json results to print.

If your json was:

```
array(
    'person' => array(
        'name' => 'timmy',
        'age' => '5'
    ),
    'car' => array(
        'make' => 'ford',
        'engine' => array(
            'hp' => 260,
            'cyls' => 8
        )
     )
 )
```

Then $flat will look like:

```
array(
    'person_name' => 'timmy',
    'person_age' => 5,
    'car_make' => 'ford',
    'car_engine_hp' => 260,
    'car_engine_cyls' => 8
)
```

and if you wanted printed in a nice html table:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach ($flat as $header => $value) {
    echo "<th>$header</th>;
}

echo "</tr><tr>";

foreach ($flat as $header => $value) {
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: OP has said they used `print_r()` already, which is far more readable than `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

I am slight confuse. but if you're referring to an xml file that will appear somethign like this :

```
 <books> 
  <book published="2011-07-24 19:40:26"> 
  <title>I left my heart on Europa</title> 
   <author>Ship of Nomads</author>
 < /book>
  <book published="2011-07-24 19:40:26"> 
  <title>I left my liveron Europa</title> 
   <author>Ship of Nomads</author>
 < /book> 
</books>
```

You can do some php trick here by using **simplexml_load_file**. 
Example  from the above xml you can have this code :

```
    $mybooks= simplexml_load_file('books.xml'); 
echo "<ul id="booklist">"; 
foreach ($mybooks as $bookinfo):
 $title=$bookinfo->title; 
$author=$bookinfo->author; 
$date=$bookinfo['published']; 
echo "<li><div class="title">".$title."</div><div class="author">by ".$author."</div><b>".$date."</b></li>";
 endforeach; echo "</ul>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I meant is, I am receiving XML data and so I do not know the fields. In that way, how do I display the XML data?